# Application or Object Defined error in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error when i input this code into my macro, with the error message stating that its an object defined error. Can i know where the error is coming from?

```
Option Explicit

Public Const strSA As String = "C:\Users\kentan\Desktop\Managed Fund "

Sub iris()
Dim i As Long
With ActiveSheet
    With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1))
        .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending , _
              key2:=.Columns(2), order2:=xlAscending , _
              Header:=xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, SortMethod:=xlStroke
    End With

    For i = 2 To .Rows.Count
        If LCase(.Cells(i, "A").Value2) = LCase(.Cells(i - 1, "A").Value2) And _
           LCase(.Cells(i, "A").Value2) <> LCase(.Cells(i + 1, "A").Value2) Then
            newiris .Cells(i, "A").Value2, .Cells(i, "B").Value2
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub

Sub newiris(nm As String, nfo As String)
Application.DisplayAlerts = false
With Workbooks.Add
    Do While .Worksheets.Count > 1: .Worksheets(2).Delete: Loop
    .Worksheets(1).Cells(1, "A").Resize(1, 2) = Array(nm, nfo)
    .SaveAs filename:=strSA & nm, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    .Close savechanges:=False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = true
End Sub
```

Comment: [edit] the question and show the text of any error messages. Also, it looks like you have a formatting problem in your code example.  You should be able to debug or step through your macro, which may give you more to work on.

Comment: Please always include in which line the error occurs, otherwise we have to guess that.

Comment: `With Workbooks.Add` Should not this be only `With Workbooks` and then in a new line `.Add` as you did with `.SaveAs` and `.Close`?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns no this way as the OP did it, the `.SaveAs` and `.Close` would directly interact with the newly added workbook from `Workbooks.Add` in the with statement. Technically it is the same as using `Set wb = Workbooks.Add` and using `With wb` afterwards.

Comment: That was my first thought too Foxfire, but I tested it and it that part works fine.

Comment: Well, I learned something new today.^^. Thanks guys!

Comment: Apologies, the error is coming from the below lines                                   
            or i = 2 To .Rows.Count
            If LCase(.Cells(i, "A").Value2) = LCase(.Cells(i - 1, "A").Value2) 
            And _
             LCase(.Cells(i, "A").Value2) <> LCase(.Cells(i + 1, 
           "A").Value2) Then
            newiris .Cells(i, "A").Value2, .Cells(i, "B").Value2

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns `With` blocks can hold an object reference and avoid needing to declare a local variable for it - I use `With New Something` all the time =)

Comment: @Adam please [edit] your post to include that information, so people can see it without needing to read all the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you're reading every row in the entire sheet:

`For i = 2 To`*`.Rows.Count`*

You're then testing the value of a cell on that row and comparing it to the row below:

`LCase(.Cells(`*`i + 1`*`, "A").Value2)`

If you're on the last row (`1,048,576`) - you can't compare that to the next row (`1,048,577`) as that row doesn't exist.

Try using:

`For i = 2 To .Rows.Count`*`-1`*

Or better yet, get it to only scan the rows with data:

`For i = 2 To`*`.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`*